# locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion: Callback with wrong region

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm using the `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:` for region monitoring. Sometimes the callback contains the wrong region even if the right regions where shown in `CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions`.

The `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:` message:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Started monitoring %@ region", region.identifier);
    NSLog(@"Monitored regions: %@", self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
}
```

Here a sample output (with changed longitude/latidue to save place)

```
2013-12-13 20:01:34.047 N[] Started monitoring Hamburg region
2013-12-13 20:01:34.048 N[] Monitored regions: {(
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Hamburg', center:<+47.0,+8.1>, radius:1000.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Zürich', center:<+47.0,+8.0>, radius:500.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'St.Gallen', center:<+47.0,+9.0>, radius:5000.00m)
)}
2013-12-13 20:01:42.070 N[] Started monitoring Hamburg region
2013-12-13 20:01:42.072 N[] Monitored regions: {(
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Hamburg', center:<+47.0,+8.1>, radius:1000.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Zürich', center:<+47.0,+8.0>, radius:500.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'St.Gallen', center:<+47.0,+9.0>, radius:5000.00m)
)}
2013-12-13 20:01:46.837 N[] Started monitoring Hamburg region
2013-12-13 20:01:46.839 N[] Monitored regions: {(
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Hamburg', center:<+47.0,+8.1>, radius:1000.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Zürich', center:<+47.0,+8.0>, radius:500.00m),
    CLCircularRegion (identifier:'St.Gallen', center:<+47.0,+9.0>, radius:5000.00m)
)}
```

I start monitoring in `didUpdateLocations` which is called back after I call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [manager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    if (locations && [locations count]){
        CLLocation* position = [locations lastObject];
        NSLog(@"New Location latitude: %f longitude %f", position.coordinate.latitude, position.coordinate.longitude);
        //self.geofences.allValues is containing Hamburg,Zürich and St.Gallen
        for(CLCircularRegion *geofence in self.geofences.allValues) {
            if(![self.locationManager.monitoredRegions containsObject:geofence]){
                [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence];
            }
            if([geofence containsCoordinate:[position coordinate]]){
                [self locationManager:manager didEnterRegion:geofence];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `didEnterRegion` is `@synchronized` to guarantee atomicity.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you mean with wrong? seems that you stay in hamburg, hummel, hummel :-) and what else region should be returned in this case?

Comment: I can't tell what problem you are trying to solve. How are registering the regions? Show us some of your code and clarify your issue.

Comment: @DeanDavids I've added some code. The problem is that I start Monitoring for 3 Regions (Hambug, Zürich and St.Gallen). So after that I expect 3 Callbacks with these regions. Sometimes I get the three (different) monitored regions, sometimes I don't (as seen above)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it would appear to register the same region repeatedly. My suspicion would lead me to put some additional NSLog calls in there to verify the contents of your source, self.geofences. Another thing I would do is put a break in there to observe values and conditionals in your For loop.

Two other items I would check:

1. confirm that you are getting the expected result from `if(![self.locationManager.monitoredRegions containsObject:geofence]){` . The objects in CLLocationManager are not guaranteed to be identical to what you initially registered. You should be testing for the identifier proper using isEqualToString. It is possible you are replacing your regions unintentionally as you have it written.
2. If the region was registered already, I don't think you need to call `didEnterRegion` . Boundary events are reported between launches. Even if the app was terminated it should handle this automatically at relaunch.

If none of that sheds light on the issue, I would look at how and when you are starting/stopping location services. Is it possible that each of those calls are another iteration of the didUpdateLocations method?

I expect that the first time that this is called, in a brand new session, monitoredRegions is empty so your process works as expected. I see reason for possible unpredictable behavior on subsequent location updates.

I would start by changing your for loop completely with this.

```
if (locations && locations.count) {
    CLLocation* position = [locations lastObject];
    NSSet *regionIdentifiers = [self.locationManager.monitoredRegions valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    NSSet *regionsForMonitoring = [NSSet setWithArray:self.geofences.allValues];
    NSSet *unMonitoredRegions = [regionsForMonitoring objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        CLCircularRegion *regionForTest = (CLCircularRegion *)obj;
        if (![regionIdentifiers containsObject:regionForTest.identifier]) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }];

    for (CLCircularRegion *geofence in unMonitoredRegions) {
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence];
        // We'll check if we are in the new region as it was not previously monitored
        if([geofence containsCoordinate:[position coordinate]]){
            [self locationManager:manager didEnterRegion:geofence];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @DeanDavids the for loop registers (in 3 iterations) the three (and only three) different regions. Otherwise the `monitoredRegions` log in the callback would not show these three regions. right?
The wrong callback happens even on the first run (resetted simulator).

I'm using the `didEnterRegion` only for the first app start. I don't recieve a didEnter-Callback when I'm already in the region.

Comment: Why I can't use `self.locationManager.monitoredRegions containsObject:geofence`? I think containsObject is doing a "deep"-equal test (and not just references) and `self.geofences` can only change if the app is restarted (I guarantee that!).

Comment: From the CLLocationManager Class Reference- "The objects in this set may not necessarily be the same objects you specified at registration time. Only the region data itself is maintained by the system. Therefore, the only way to uniquely identify a registered region is using its identifier property."

Comment: I am putting your code in a knock up of my own. Let me see what I can discover.

Comment: I recently noticed that it only happens when im debugging. But I think that doesn't matter?

Comment: Well, I put your code in a mock up and it does not show the problem you describe. I see the regions registered and proper response on initial start. All launches afterwards skip registration as the regions already exist in monitoredRegions. Your issue must be coming from some code you have not provided. Perhaps you can send me a mock up of your own that demonstrates your issue. As for the test for regions,  I would still prefer my method in following the reference document recommendation.

Comment: I don't think debugging yes/no makes a difference. I am testing on simulator and do not get the same output as you do. Need more of your code to determine why.

Comment: Another thing that may be a factor is whatever you are doing in locationManager:didEnterRegion: . Anything there?